# Appending Date to the end of line in multiple textbox

Tags: c#

[image]

how could i add a date to the very end of each line with another font and size ?!
for example i want to add 1:15 AM to the end of  "hello World" line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it doesn't have to be a textbox, you can apply some nice formatting using some manipulation of datagridview.

Using 2 columns with the formatting and colors changed to match the rest of the controls.

It's just as easy to add lines to.

```
        dataTextView.Rows.Add(txtAddText.Text, DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
```

Example source: http://mcspazzy.com/code/TextDisplay.zip

[image: Test Example]

Comment: i like this anwser, maybe not the best way to do it. but its nice to think out of the box, upvote

Comment: thanks its an brilliant answer, by the way i found another solution where i use UserControl and design it as i want then adding it to a FlowLayoutPanel.

Answer (score 1):

[AppendText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.appendtext.aspx) exists for WinForms TextBoxes

```
 textBox1.AppendText(DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt"));
```

However, changing font and size for a just a part of a TextBox is not possible,
You need a [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx) for that

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
foreach(string s in richTextBox1.Lines)
{
    sb.AppendLine(s + " "+DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm"));
}
richTextBox1.Text=sb.ToString();
```

Comment: i tried AppendText but my purpose is to add the date to the very end

Comment: Well, the textbox has a property [Lines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.lines.aspx) that is a string array of every line present in the multiline. You could loop over that property and append the time to each line

Comment: i changed to RichTextBox now how could i add a date to the end of line like in chat ?!

Comment: Sorry time to go for me, added a loop to append to each line the current datetime (works for textboxes and also for richtextbox) The font and size part need to be searched. There are numerous examples